# not able to insert bulk record using php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Provided with this array, i am trying to insert it into the table using **insert_batch**.

`$arrayOfQuestions` contains multiple array like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_desc] => In human beings, partial pressure of carbon dioxide in the inspired and expired air is respectively
            [option_a] => 0.3 and 40 mm Hg
            [option_b] => 0.3 and 32 mm Hg
            [option_c] => 40 and 46 mm Hg
            [option_d] => 40 and 0.3 mm Hg
            [answer] => B
            [diff_level] => 4
            [solution] => Refer answer.
            [chapter_id] => 54
            [inst_id] => 1
            [subject_id] => 68
            [ref_q_id] => 8540371983
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_desc] => At high altitude, RBCs of human blood will
            [option_a] => Increase in number
            [option_b] => Decrease in number
            [option_c] => Decrease in size
            [option_d] => Increase in size
            [answer] => A
            [diff_level] => 2
            [solution] => At higher altitudes, due to low pressure of atmospheric oxygen, the body has to carry more oxygen than normal in per volume of blood to supply the body constantly. The increased number of RBC in blood ensures the presence of more haemoglobin and thus more oxygen is carried.
            [chapter_id] => 54
            [inst_id] => 1
            [subject_id] => 68
            [ref_q_id] => 8540371983
        )
)
```

I am getting **return true** with the code i have tried below but data is **not inserted to the table**..

```
$result = $this->db->insert_batch('test_temp_question', $arrayOfQuestions);
```

Comment: `insert_batch` returns either the number of rows inserted or FALSE. What is the actual value of $result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for successfully insert data use condition for it:

```
if($result>0){
echo"successfull.";
}
else{
echo"not successfull";
}
```